# Use Reveal.js with Polymer

Tags: polymer, reveal.js

I have a project with Polymer + Reveal.js

I have a view with polymer that gets all the Slides/Sections.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[my.slides]]" as="slide">
    <section>
        <h1>slide.title</h1>
        <h2>slide.content</h2>
    </section>
</template>
```

When I try to start Reveal.js, I have the issue related to:

> (index):21136 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'querySelectorAll' of undefined

I think is because Reveal.js cannot select a Webcomponent generated by Polymer, because Reveal.js needs to have all slides content wrote on the html file by separate.

Then my question is: How to use Polymer Webcomponents with Reveal,js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan: Yes, you are right.

Now I am creating DOM elements directly with JS avoiding Polymer shadowDOM elements.

Then I created a function called createSlides where - based in a JSON response - I appending slides (sections) within slides div.

Fist I create a Polymer template similar to:

```
<template>
    <div class="reveal">
        <div id="slides" class="slides">
             <section>
                 This section will be removed
             </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Next I removed the unused slide and appended some slides. Finally start the Reveal presentation

```
ready()
{
    this.removeInitialSlide();
    this.addSomeSlides();
    this.startRevealPresentation();
}

clearInitialSlides()
{
    var slidesComp = this.$.slides;
    while (slidesComp.hasChildNodes()) {
        slidesComp.removeChild(slidesComp.lastChild);
    }
}

addSomeSlides()
{
    var slide1 = document.createElement("section");
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "some/path/to/image.jpg";
    slide1.appendChild(image);

    this.$.slides.appendChild(slide1);

    var slide2 = document.createElement("section");
    slide2.innerHTML = "<h1>Test content</h1>"

    this.$.slides.appendChild(slide2);
}
```

Working fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you most likely can't use reveal.js in a web component created with Polymer right now and here's why.

If you look at [reveal.js's code](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/js/reveal.js#L282) it looks for dom elements with the `reveal` and `slides` classes on the main document like this:

```
dom.wrapper = document.querySelector( '.reveal' );
dom.slides = document.querySelector( '.reveal .slides' );
```

The problem with that is that Polymer elements have their own [local dom](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom) which is a different dom tree which can't be accessed using methods like `document.querySelector` which means reveal.js can't access to them.

Comment: Yes you are right, I added my own answer, probably is not the best but is working fine.